# converting a Fanuc g-code including Macro-B to basic syntax

Tags: python, regex, string, g-code

I have a g-code written in Fanuc g-code format including Macro-B (more info [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/CNC/comments/b9xsal/many_dialects_of_gcode/)), for example

```
#101 = 2.0 (first variable)
#102 = 0.1 (second variable)
#103 = [#101 + #102 * 3] (third variable using simple arithmetic)
G01 X#101 Y#103 F0.1
```

which should be converted to:

```
G01 X1.0 Y2.3 F0.1
```

more elaborate examples [here](https://lab.whitequark.org/notes/2014-02-12/parametric-g-code-for-cutting-pcbs/) and [here](https://benjaminjurke.com/content/articles/2015/gcode-primer/).

things to be changed:

1. all instances of a variable slot should be replace with its value:

`(#\d+)\s*=\s*(-?\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*)`

2. arithmetic `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` inside the `[...]` need to be calculated:

`(#\d+)\s*=\s*\[(#\d+|(-?\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*))(\s*[+\-*/]\s*(#\d+|(-?\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*|\d+)))*\]`

3. comments `(...)` could be ignored or removed.

I would appreciate if you could help me know how i can do this in Python and if the regex I have above is correct. Thanks for your support in advance.

**P.S.1.** Unfortunately I can't find the syntax highlighting for fenced code blocks for g-code

**P.S.2.** when changing floats to strings one should consider the issue with Python floating point handeling. I made this function to solve that:

```py
def f32str(inputFloat):
    """
    This function converts a Python float to a string with 3 decimals
    """
    return str(f"{inputFloat:.3f}")
```

Comment: You are missing the `-?` on the second half of #1. Also you aren't catching whole integers, are they valid? IE: `#101=1`. Can you redefine a defined variable in the middle of a program? That would change your logic for the regexing in step #1. In #2 is there a limit of how many arithmetic operations are allowed? Right now you have it limited to 1 operation.

Comment: Dear @RobR. thanks for the comment. Have you seen my post below? how do you think about it? 1. the `-?` I have fixed below. 2. what do you mean that I'm not catching all integers? `1` is not a valid value `1.` is the correct form in most of the standards

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a piece of code which does the job. Assuming `gcode` is a multiline string read from a Fanuc G-code:

```py
import re
import os

def f32str(inputFloat):
    return str(f"{inputFloat:.3f}")

gcode = re.sub(r"\(.*?\)", "", gcode)

flag = len(re.findall(r"#\d+", gcode))

while 0 < flag:
    cases = re.findall(r"((#\d+)\s*=\s*([-+]?\s*(\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?\d*)))", gcode)
    for case in cases:
        gcode = gcode.replace(case[0], "")
        gcode = gcode.replace(case[0], case[1])
    cases = re.findall(r"(\[(\s*[+-]?\s*(\d+(\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)(\s*[-+*\/]\s*[+-]?\s*(\d+(\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)\s*)*)\])", gcode)
    for case in cases:
        gcode = gcode.replace(case[0], f32str(eval(case[1])))
    flag = len(re.findall(r"#\d+", gcode))

gcode = os.linesep.join([s for s in gcode.splitlines() if s.strip()])
```

this is probably the worst way to do this and there should be more efficient implementations. I will leave the rest to the Python experts.